# Require at least one property of given type

Tags: typescript

consider the following code

```
class FootballService {
  getMatches() { return [] }
}

function defineMatchesOnComponent(component: X) {
  component.matches = Object.values(component)
    .find(property => property instanceof FootballService)
    .getMatches();
}

class ComponentA {
  constructor(public footballService: FootballService, public otherProp: string) {}
}

class ComponentB {
  constructor(public whateverNameYouWant: FootballService, public otherProp: number) {}
}

class ComponentC {
  constructor(public otherProp: string) {}
}

const a = new ComponentA(new FootballService(), 'xd');
const b = new ComponentB(new FootballService(), 2);
const c = new ComponentC(true);
```

is it possible to define such type `X` that the following will happen:

```
defineMatchesOnComponent(a); // should be ok
defineMatchesOnComponent(b); // should be ok
defineMatchesOnComponent(c); // should be type error
```

In other words is it possible to require at least one property but it may have any name ?

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fekr1o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure we can do better than a custom error. We can force a type error on the parameter using a conditional type if the union of values in the type (`T[keyof T]`) does not contain `FootballService`

```
class FootballService {
  getMatches() { return [] }
}

function defineMatchesOnComponent<T>(component: T & (FootballService extends T[keyof T] ? {} : "No FootballService property was defined")) {
   /* */
}

class ComponentA {
  constructor(public footballService: FootballService, public otherProp: string) {}
}

class ComponentB {
  constructor(public whateverNameYouWant: FootballService, public otherProp: number) {}
}

class ComponentC {
  constructor(public otherProp: boolean) {}
}

const a = new ComponentA(new FootballService(), 'xd');
const b = new ComponentB(new FootballService(), 2);
const c = new ComponentC(true);


defineMatchesOnComponent(a); // should be ok
defineMatchesOnComponent(b); // should be ok
defineMatchesOnComponent(c); // should be type error
```

Comment: Dude, you're like typescript equivalent of unbeatable video game boss. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @WilhelmOlejnik  That is a fresh title you gave me. Thanks 